# mongoDB query for retrieving from nested array collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576155a6cd87b68f7e6e42c9"),
    "First_Name" : "ok",
    "Last_Name" : "jaao",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Last_Login" : "Wed, Jun 14, 2016 6:48 PM",
            "Class" : "fb",
            "ID" : "123"
        },
        {
            "Last_Login" : "Wed, Jun 15, 2016 6:48 PM",
            "ID" : "111",
            "Class" : "fb"
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576155ccf6d8979e7e77df27"),
    "First_Name" : "abc",
    "Last_Name" : "xyz",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Last_Login" : "Wed, Jun 15, 2016 6:49 PM",
            "Class" : "fb",
            "ID" : "123"
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

This is my json structure. and I want a mongoDB query which retrieves every user that has logged in today i.e., whose `Last_Login` has today's date.

I want my output as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576155a6cd87b68f7e6e42c9"),
    "First_Name" : "ok",
    "Last_Name" : "jaao",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Last_Login" : "Wed, Jun 15, 2016 6:48 PM",
            "ID" : "111",
            "Class" : "fb"
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 2
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("576155ccf6d8979e7e77df27"),
    "First_Name" : "abc",
    "Last_Name" : "xyz",
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "Sessions" : [
        {
            "Last_Login" : "Wed, Jun 15, 2016 6:49 PM",
            "Class" : "fb",
            "ID" : "123"
        }
    ],
    "Count" : 1
}
```

Comment: Dates stored like that will need complex queries that may be ineffective. Consider changing your schema to have `Last_Login` dates stored as `ISODate()`

Comment: Last_Login field contains data in the format of moment().format('llll') provided by moment.js library, do i still need to change it to ISODate() ???

Comment: Yes, it's better to store dates in MongoDB as proper Date() types instead of storing them as strings in the above format.

Comment: can u please give me an example of inserting it as an ISODate(), ryt now im using it as : Last_Login : moment.format('llll')

Comment: `moment()` has a [**`toDate()`**](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method that you can use as it returns a JavaScript Date object or simply create a new instance of the JS Date object. So you can do it like `Last_Login: moment().toDate()` or as `Last_Login: new Date()`

Comment: ok.. got it done using Date() but im not getting the expected output. it outputs all the data inside the matching object, even the yesterday's login time, please loook carefully at my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$Sessions"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "Sessions.Last_Login": {
                $gte: ISODate("2016-06-16T00:00:00.0Z"),
                $lt: ISODate("2016-06-17T00:00:00.0Z")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$_id",
                First_Name: "$First_Name",
                Last_Name: "$Last_Name"
            },
            Sessions: {
                $push: "$Sessions"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$_id._id",
            First_Name: "$_id.First_Name",
            Last_Name: "$_id.Last_Name",
            Sessions: "$Sessions"
        }
    }
])
```

So the query will do those steps:

1. `$unwind` all `Sessions` elements
2. `$match` documents inside the date range
3. `$group` together documents by `_id`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`
4. `$project` documents to look like the original format

I omitted some fields, but you can easily add it in `$group` and `$project` steps. And of course you'll need to change the date range.

I'm concerned about the performance of this query in a big collection. Maybe is better if you use the first query I gave and filter the sessions you want in your code.

**Edit:**

As @chridam said, this query will work only if you change `Last_Login` to `ISODate()`, what is recommended.

**Edit 2:**

Updating the query to use `aggregate` and match the request of only fetch `Sessions` inside the date range.

This is the old version:

```
db.users.filter({
    'Sessions': {
        '$elemMatch': {
            'Last_Login': {
                '$gte': ISODate("2016-06-16T00:00:00.0Z"),
                '$lt': ISODate("2016-06-17T00:00:00.0Z")
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Not so sure if the query will work since the `Last_Login` date is given by the OP as a string.

Comment: @chridam Sure, I didn't notice.

Comment: it says ISODate() not defined... other alternatives??

Comment: ok.. got it done using Date() but im not getting the expected output. it outputs all the data inside the matching object, even the yesterday's login time

Comment: So you want to return only the last login session?

Comment: no.. the entries corresponding to only todays sessions

Comment: You'll need a more complicated query with `aggregate`. Look at the update.