# Return only the array element on which a text search matched

Tags: arrays, mongodb, full-text-search

Suppose I create the following db/collection:

```
use articles

db.stores.insert( [ 
             {_id : 1, arr : ['abc xyz', 'def']}, 
             {_id : 2, arr : ['jadskf', 'ljh abc']}])

db.stores.createIndex({"arr" : "text"})
```

I want to do text search over the arrays `arr` and obtain only the array elements that match the search.

For instance,

```
> db.stores.find({$text : {$search : "abc"}})
{ "_id" : 1, "arr" : [ "abc xyz", "def" ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "arr" : [ "jadskf", "ljh abc" ] }
```

Ideally I'd like to only obtain the first element of the `arr` in the first document: `abc xyz` and only the second element of the `arr` in the second document: `ljh abc`, and also the `_id` of the matched documents.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Note that what I want is not a simple projection of the `arr` element, but of the elements of the `arr` where the match occurred.

I'm using Mongo 3.2.7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mongoDB query for retrieving from nested array collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836891/mongodb-query-for-retrieving-from-nested-array-collection)

Comment: @LuizdePrá this is a bit different problem

Answer (score 0):

my first thought was that we can use `$elemMatch` and problem solved, but ... there is no text search on `$elemMatch`.

Having a look from other angle, we can use regex in this case, as first expensive scan thru collection is done my text search index, then regex will be a perfect solution.

```
db.stores.find({
    $text : {
        $search : "abc"
    }
}, {
    arr : {
        $elemMatch : {
            $regex : /abc/i
        }
    }
})
```

Any comments welcome!

Comment: That does solve the problem, but it's not optimal. Besides doing the search twice (I agree it's not over the entire data set the second time), the semantics of the text search are different than a simple regex, e.g., stop words, stemming, etc, are employed on a text search. Mongo knows internally where the matches occur, but it doesn't seem to expose that as easily.

Comment: @CassioPereira agree, but even aggregation framework is nt helpful in this problem as `$text` search can be used only in first pipeline stage (and the problem is that we need to do it twice :( )